# paramiko exec_command hangs after a few commands

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, cisco

im connecting a linux server with sshclient  .And then, im connecting cisco routers via telnet on this server. I'm connecting server and execute telnet command perfectly but in second or third telnet command code get stucked and doesnt throw error.Here is part of my code:

```
def __init__(self):
        self.pre_client=paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.pre_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        sellf.pre_client.connect("server",username="user",password="password")
        self.client=self.pre_client.invoke_shell()
 def connect(self,ip):
   o=self.client.recv(1024)
   print o
   self.client.exec_command("telnet %s\n"%(ip))
   while True:
       o=self.client.recv(1024)
       print o
       #EXECUTE COMMAND ON ROUTER
       self.client.exec_command("exit\n")
       if 'exit' in o:
           break
```

Why it get stuck on this command? How can i handle it?

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd need to see more code to find what's wrong. If you don't have a specific reason for needing to use a Paramiko Channel, life will probably be a lot easier for you if you just use a Paramiko Client. This is a rough snippet from an old script of mine:

```
def ssh_connect(usr, pswds, host):

    # Open Connection - auto add policy
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    # Retry with multiple passwords
    for pswd in pswds:
        try:
            ssh.connect(host, username=usr, password=pswd)
            return ssh
        except:
            pass
    else:
        print("Could not login to: " + host)
        return None


def send_command(conn, command):
    try:
        stdin, stdout, stderr = conn.exec_command(command)
        if stdout:
            for str in stdout:
                sys.stdout.write("\t%s" % str)
            return True
        if stderr:
            for str in stderr:
                sys.stderr.write("\t%s" % str)
            return False
        else:
            print("\n")
        return True

    except paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException as e:
        print(e.message)
        return False
```

And of course, call them with:

```
conn = ssh_connect(login, passwords, host)
send_command(conn, command)
```

Comment: when i print the output i observed that my commands are not printed correctly. For example if i send exit command it prints like :
ex
-it
but responses are printed properly. İs it realeted my problem?

Comment: Is this on the first host, or the second telnet'd host?

Comment: I dunno man, it's hard to tell from your code snippet. You can check the commands are running okay via ssh with a simple `'echo command'`, but I doubt it's failing there. Also worth noting, if you're trying to send two commands at once, you need to end each command with a semi-colon: `cd /var/tmp; ls -la`. Afraid I can't help more than that.